# sum total depending for each department without duplicates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to sum total depending for each department without duplicates.

Yesterday user @yBrodsky helped me with that and suggested to use SQL but today I want to add a couple options and I can't do this in sql.

Main problem:

I have an array like:

```
var data = [{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"83"
},{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"41"
},{
  dept:"other",
  task_time:"10"
}];
```

And I want to sum task_time for every dept: for example test = 124 and other = 10. 
There is a function which should calculate it but it works like test = 83. test = 41 and other = 10. And shows every dept instead one with sum.

There is function.

```
var totalPerDept = {};
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  if(!totalPerDept[item.dept]) {
    totalPerDept[item.dept] = 0;
  }
  totalPerDept[item.dept] += parseFloat(item.task_time);
});
```

Here's the above as a snippet:

```js
var data = [{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"83"
},{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"41"
},{
  dept:"other",
  task_time:"10"
}];

var totalPerDept = {};
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  if(!totalPerDept[item.dept]) {
    totalPerDept[item.dept] = 0;
  }
  totalPerDept[item.dept] += parseFloat(item.task_time);
});
console.log(totalPerDept);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"There is a function which should calculate it but it works like test = 83. test = 41 and other = 10"* No, it doesn't. It does exactly what you said you want. I've copied it into a snippet for you demonstrating that.

Comment: Have you looked into using `Array.prototype.reduce`?

Comment: Hang on, the code you've provided does exactly what you want... _"example test = 124 and other = 10"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The above is fine. You can *also* use `reduce` (although some say it's an *ab*use rather than use if the accumulator doesn't change, as it wouldn't above).

Comment: Your code is fine, and according to snippet, its working well..

Comment: I am taking data from JSON using response.data and this function doesn't calculate.  It only taking every dept with value task_time and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I did some modifications to your code to obtain an array with the result you want:

```
     function sumDeptData() {
        var data = [{
              dept:"test",
              task_time:"83"
            },{
              dept:"test",
              task_time:"41"
            },{
              dept:"other",
              task_time:"10"
            }];

        var totalPerDept = [];

        angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
            var index = findWithAttr(totalPerDept, 'dept', item.dept);

            if (index < 0) {
                totalPerDept.push({
                    dept: item.dept,
                    total: parseFloat(item.task_time)
                });
            } else {
                totalPerDept[index].total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
            }
        });

        return totalPerDept;
    }

    function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
            if(array[i][attr] === value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

sumDeptData() returns [{"dept":"test","total":124},{"dept":"other","total":10}]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Plain JavaScript.

```js
var data = [{
    dept: "test",
    task_time: "83"
  }, {
    dept: "test",
    task_time: "41"
  }, {
    dept: "other",
    task_time: "10"
  }],
  minArr = [];

data.forEach(function(v) {
  if (!this[v.dept]) {
    this[v.dept] = {
      dept: v.dept,
      task_time: 0
    };
    minArr.push(this[v.dept]);
  }
  this[v.dept].task_time = parseInt(this[v.dept].task_time) + parseInt(v.task_time);
}, {});

console.log(minArr);
```

Comment: Your code works and also code @Javi_Swift works but... If I have my data from JSON which looks like your array it doesn't work hmm? It sum only t ovalue 255

Comment: @NelsonBiggety Perhaps you are summing up chars instead of numbers?

Comment: @Javi_Swift in database it's as INTEGER

Comment: @NelsonBiggety are you getting 255 in client (JS) or in server (services, DB,...)? If you are getting this result in your JS controller, it looks like you are getting the values of the JSON as String an summing their ASCII value. Try casting them to num before summing them. In my code I use the parseFloat function to do this task.